# Change highlight colour on scroll in React js

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, navbar

I am having an issue with my code for my Navbar.jsx component. I have implemented a function the navbar background and text changes colour on scroll which works fine but what I want is for the :hover colours to take effect as well but only one hover colour takes effect.

so far, only the 'nav-list' a:hover selector takes effect but after scrolling past 650px, its still using 'nav-list' a:hover when I want it use 'nav-list-colour' a:hover selector at that point.

Navbar.jsx component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Logo from './Logo.jsx'
import '../App.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    const state = useState()

    const navigation = [
      {_id:101, title: 'ABOUT US', href: '/'},
      {_id:102, title: 'SHOP', href: '/Shop'},
      {_id:103, title: 'MENU', href: '/Careers'},
      {_id:104, title: 'CONTACT US', href: '/Contact-Us'},
    ];
    
    const [colour, setColour] = useState(false)

    const changeColour = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 650) {
        setColour(true) 
      } else {
        setColour(false)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColour)

  return (
    <div className={colour ? 'navbar navbarbg' : 'navbar'}>
      <div className="container">
        <Logo />
        <ul 
          className={colour ? 'nav-list nav-list-colour' : 'nav-list'}
          >
          {
            navigation.map((item) => (
              <a href={item?.href} key={item._id}>
                <li>
                  {item?.title}
                  <span className={`${item?.href === state && 'style=color: blue;'}`}></span>
                </li>
              </a>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
        <div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

This is my style.css file

```
.nav-list {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: larger;
  position: relative; top: -30px; left: 300px;
}

.nav-list a {
  /* color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%); */
  color: hsl(48, 54%, 89%);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-underline-offset: 0.2em;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.nav-list-colour a {
  color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
}

.nav-list-colour a:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 181, 103);
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  /* color: rgb(200, 181, 103); */
  color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
  text-underline-offset: 0.4em;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

I have tried setting up another function with an if statement effecting colour ONLY but it stopped showing changes all together. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a CSS specificity issue. Try changing the UL component to

```
<ul className={colour ? 'nav-list colour' : 'nav-list'} >
```

And update the CSS to this

```
.nav-list.colour a:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 181, 103);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the problem with it though. The CSS selectors just needed to be rearranged a little. I moved the .nav-list a:hover {} selector underneath the .nav-list a {} selector and it fixed it. Thank you though.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! However I would agree with what @drew-reese mentioned in his answer that the recommend solution would be to change the CSS specificity of the rules. Whilst changing the order may fix it, if you ever re-order or update your CSS for another reason you could accidentally put them in the wrong order again and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is CSS selector specificity. `".nav-list a:hover"` and `".nav-list-colour a:hover"` have the same specificity and so it seems the rule defined later in CSS is what is applied.

You have at least a couple options to resolve this:

1. Reorder the CSS rules so the `".nav-list-colour"` rules are defined *after* the `".nav-list"` rules.

   ```css
   .nav-list {
     font-weight: bold;
     display: flex;
     gap: 50px;
     list-style-type: none;
     justify-content: center;
     font-size: larger;
     position: relative; top: -30px; left: 300px;
   }

   .nav-list a {
     color: hsl(48, 54%, 89%);
     text-decoration: none;
     text-underline-offset: 0.2em;
     transition-duration: 500ms;
   }

   .nav-list a:hover {
     color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
     text-underline-offset: 0.4em;
     transition-duration: 300ms;
     text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px;
   }

   .nav-list-colour a {
     color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
   }

   .nav-list-colour a:hover {
     color: rgb(200, 181, 103);
   }
   ```
2. Bump the selector specificity of the `".nav-list-colour"` selectors so that they are *more* specific.

   ```css
   .nav-list {
     font-weight: bold;
     display: flex;
     gap: 50px;
     list-style-type: none;
     justify-content: center;
     font-size: larger;
     position: relative; top: -30px; left: 300px;
   }

   .nav-list a {
     /* color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%); */
     color: hsl(48, 54%, 89%);
     text-decoration: none;
     text-underline-offset: 0.2em;
     transition-duration: 500ms;
   }

   .nav-list.nav-list-colour a { // <-- higher specificity
     color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
   }

   .nav-list.nav-list-colour a:hover { // <-- higher specificity
     color: rgb(200, 181, 103);
   }

   .nav-list a:hover {
     /* color: rgb(200, 181, 103); */
     color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
     text-underline-offset: 0.4em;
     transition-duration: 300ms;
     text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px;
   }
   ```

Between these two options I would recommend bumping the specificity so the order of the CSS rules is less important.

***Unrelated but highly recommended suggestion***: Update the logic in the `Navbar` to apply the scroll event listener in a `useEffect` hook so that it's not creating new lister instances each time the component renders.

Example:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  ...
  const [colour, setColour] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeColour = () => {
      setColour(window.scrollY >= 650);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeColour);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeColour);
    };
  }, []);

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you, i figured out that it was the arrangement of the selectors that was the problem and changed it. As for your suggestion for the useEffect hook, that is much appreciated and I will implement it.

Comment: @ryanl Welcome, glad to help. I still recommend you address this using the specificity so you don't accidentally re-introduce this "bug" in later edits to your CSS rules. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese, I will do. Also how could I add to my current 'changeColour' function to change colour on scroll on a specific page e.g. Home page = window.scrollY >= 650, AboutUs Page = window.scrollY >= 100 etc? Thank you.

Comment: @ryanl I'd create a map with path as key and the offset as value, something like `const offsets = { "/": 650, "/about": 100, ... };` and use `window.location.pathname` in the `changeColour` handler, something like `setColour(window.scrollY >= offsets[window.location.pathname] ?? 650);`. Does this make sense? If you need more specific help though it would be better to create an entirely new post for the specific issue/question. Feel free to ping me in a comment here with a link to the post if you do that and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Drew Reese. I think i understand but here is the link to my new post anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78187680/navbar-colour-change-on-scroll-effect-for-homepage-only/78187720?noredirect=1#comment137843919_78187720