# navbar colour change on scroll effect for homepage only

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, react-router-dom

I have created a `changeColour` function where the navbar changes colour after scrolling beyond a certain point which works perfectly. The problem is I only want it to take effect on my Home page and every other page (AboutUs, Shop, ContactUs) continues with my `.navbarbg .nav-list-green a .nav-list-green a:hover` selectors.

Here is my code so far:

edited:  I edited this question to show what I did initially inside `const changeColour {}`.

Navbar.jsx

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from './Logo.jsx'
import '../App.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    const state = useState()

    const navigation = [ 
      {_id:101, title: 'ABOUT US', href: '/AboutUs'},
      {_id:102, title: 'SHOP', href: '/Shop'},
      {_id:103, title: 'MENU', href: '/Menu'},
      {_id:104, title: 'CONTACT US', href: '/ContactUs'},
    ];
    
    const [colour, setColour] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      const changeColour = () => {
        if (isItHomePage()) setColour(window.scrollY >= 650)
      };
        function isItHomePage() {
          return window.location.href.indexOf("/") === 
       0;
     }


      window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColour);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColour)
      }
    }, [])
    

  return (
    <div className={colour ? 'navbar navbarbg' : 'navbar'}>
      <div className="container">
        <Logo />
        <ul className={colour ? 'nav-list-beige nav-list-green' : 'nav-list-beige'}
          >
          {
            navigation.map((item) => (
              <Link to={item?.href} key={item._id}>
                <li className={colour ? 'nav-link nav-link-colour' : 'nav-link'}>
                  {item?.title}
                  <span className={`${item?.href === state && 'style=color: blue;'}`}></span>
                </li>
              </Link>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
        <div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

My App.css

```css
/* navbar.jsx CSS */
.navbarbg {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px); 
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px hsl(0, 0%, 63%);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.navbar {
  /* (green) background-color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%, 90%); */
  /* background-color: hsl(49, 87%, 88%); */
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid black; */
  position: fixed; top: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:99;
  transition-duration: 500ms
}

.nav-list-beige {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: larger;
  display: flex;
  position: relative; top: -30px; left: 350px;
}

.nav-list-beige a {
  color: hsl(48, 54%, 89%);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.nav-list-beige a:hover {
  color: hsl(48, 100%, 85%);
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px;
}

.nav-list-green a {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

.nav-list-green a:hover {
  color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%);
}
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated please?

Answer (score 0):

At the

```
      const changeColour = () => {
        setColour(window.scrollY >= 650)
      };
```

part, you could have a conditional, like

```
      const changeColour = () => {
        if (isItHomePage()) setColour(window.scrollY >= 650)
      };
```

and then you will need to implement `isItHomePage` like

```
function isItHomePage() {
    return window.location.href.indexOf("<your home url>") === 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work unfortunately. Are you supposed to insert the function isItHomePage() inside the changeColour arrow function or anywhere inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: You need to insert it at a place where it's available. Can you elaborate on how did this not work for you? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I didn't get an error message but it didn't do anything. I inserted it underneath ```setColour()``` value inside ```changeColour``` function.

Comment: @ryanl Are you sure you have implemented `isItHomePage` correctly? Have you tested it? Can you edit your question and add your `isItHomePage` to it?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Lajos Arpad. I edited my original question to show you what I did using the code you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook to access the current `pathname` value and the [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility to test if the current `pathname` matches a specific path, e.g. like a "home page" on `"/"`. The `pathname` should be used as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook to re-enclose the current `pathname` value in the `changeColor` handler when instantiating the scroll event listeners.

Basic Example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  const changeColour = () => {
    const isHome = matchPath("/", pathname);

    setColour(isHome && window.scrollY >= 650);
  };

  // invoke once to check in case page is already scrolled down when rendering
  changeColour();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeColour);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeColour);
  };
}, [pathname]);

...
```

Full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const navigation = [
  { _id: 100, title: "HOME", href: "/" },
  { _id: 101, title: "ABOUT US", href: "/AboutUs" },
  { _id: 102, title: "SHOP", href: "/Shop" },
  { _id: 103, title: "MENU", href: "/Menu" },
  { _id: 104, title: "CONTACT US", href: "/ContactUs" }
];

const Navbar = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const state = useState();
  const [colour, setColour] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeColour = () => {
      const isHome = matchPath("/", pathname);

      setColour(isHome && window.scrollY >= 650);
    };

    changeColour();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeColour);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeColour);
    };
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <div className={colour ? "navbar navbarbg" : "navbar"}>
      <div className="container">
        <Logo />
        <ul
          className={
            colour ? "nav-list-beige nav-list-green" : "nav-list-beige"
          }
        >
          {navigation.map((item) => (
            <Link to={item?.href} key={item._id}>
              <li className={colour ? "nav-link nav-link-colour" : "nav-link"}>
                {item?.title}
                <span
                  className={`${item?.href === state && "style=color: blue;"}`}
                ></span>
              </li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again @Drew Reese. I answered the question to you in depth what i did using your code to get my pages working correctly. I created an ```if``` statement for each page.

Comment: @ryanl thanks. I'm pretty sure your URL is not starting with "/". Please try with `alert(window.location.href)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Lajos Arpad but I got it sorted out anyway. I created ```const``` variables for each path using ```matchPath("< url />", pathname)``` and then creating an ```if``` statement for page when scroll passed certain pixel.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it working in the end. I assume there is a cleaner/simpler way of creating the variables for each page though but this is what I got so far:

Navbar.jsx

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    const state = useState()
    const [colour, setColour] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      const changeColour = () => {
       //created for each page using pathname
        const isHome = matchPath("/", pathname)
        const isAboutUs = matchPath("/AboutUs", pathname)

        // if statement for each page to display different scroll effect
        if (isHome && window.scrollY >= 650) {
          setColour(true)
        } else if (isAboutUs && window.scrollY >= 0) {
          setColour(true)
        } else {
          setColour(false)
        }
      };
      
  
      changeColour();
      window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColour);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColour)
      }
    }, [pathname])
```

full code:

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, matchPath, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from './Logo.jsx'
import '../App.css'

// Array that features all navlinks required. Will use in .map component
const navigation = [ 
  {_id:102, title: 'ABOUT US', href: '/AboutUs'},
  {_id:103, title: 'SHOP', href: '/Shop'},
  {_id:104, title: 'MENU', href: '/Menu'},
  {_id:105, title: 'CONTACT US', href: '/ContactUs'},
];

const Navbar = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    const state = useState()
    const [colour, setColour] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      const changeColour = () => {
        const isHome = matchPath("/", pathname)
        const isAboutUs = matchPath("/AboutUs", pathname)

        if (isHome && window.scrollY >= 650) {
          setColour(true)
        } else if (isAboutUs && window.scrollY >= 0) {
          setColour(true)
        } else {
          setColour(false)
        }
      };
      
      changeColour();
      window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColour);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColour)
      }
    }, [pathname])
    
  return (
    <div className={colour ? 'navbar navbarbg' : 'navbar'}>
      <div className="container">
        <Logo />
        <ul className={colour ? 'nav-list-beige nav-list-green' : 'nav-list-beige'}
          >
          {
            navigation.map((item) => (
              <Link to={item?.href} key={item._id}>
                <li className={`${item?.href === pathname && 'color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%)'}`}>
                  {item?.title}
                  <span className={`${item?.href === pathname && 'color: hsl(96, 24%, 44%)'}`}></span>
                </li>
              </Link>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
        <div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```